# Deserialise XML to a c# class

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have xml which is formed by a third party software.  I would like to extract the child elements from the outputs section of the XML into a c# class. How do i do it?

My Class definition

```
class InstrumentParameters
    {
        public string id;
        public string ChannelNumber;
        public string InstrumentParameterType;
        public string IsMetaData;
        public string Name;
    }
```

My List to store the parameters

```
List<InstrumentParameters> iParams = new List<InstrumentParameters>();
```

Finally the XML

```
<SimulatorConfigurationFile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Simulator.SharedInterfaces" z:Id="1" z:Type="SimulatorConfigurationFile" z:Assembly="Simulator.SharedInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <Inputs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConfigurationInterfaces" z:Id="2" z:Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConfigurationInterfaces.InstrumentParameter, ConfigurationInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" z:Assembly="0">
    <_items z:Id="3" z:Size="3">
      <InstrumentParameter z:Id="4">
        <ChannelNumber>0</ChannelNumber>
        <InstrumentParameterType>Double</InstrumentParameterType>
        <IsMetaData>false</IsMetaData>
        <Name z:Id="5">Test Input Parameter 1</Name>
      </InstrumentParameter>
      <InstrumentParameter z:Id="6">
        <ChannelNumber>0</ChannelNumber>
        <InstrumentParameterType>Double</InstrumentParameterType>
        <IsMetaData>false</IsMetaData>
        <Name z:Id="7">Test Input Parameter 2</Name>
      </InstrumentParameter>
      <InstrumentParameter z:Id="8">
        <ChannelNumber>0</ChannelNumber>
        <InstrumentParameterType>Double</InstrumentParameterType>
        <IsMetaData>false</IsMetaData>
        <Name z:Id="9">Test Input Parameter 3</Name>
      </InstrumentParameter>
    </_items>
    <_size>3</_size>
    <_version>0</_version>
  </Inputs>
  <Outputs xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/ConfigurationInterfaces" z:Id="10" z:Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConfigurationInterfaces.InstrumentParameter, ConfigurationInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" z:Assembly="0">
    <_items z:Id="11" z:Size="13">
      <InstrumentParameter z:Id="12">
        <ChannelNumber>0</ChannelNumber>
        <InstrumentParameterType>Double</InstrumentParameterType>
        <IsMetaData>false</IsMetaData>
        <Name z:Id="13">0</Name>
      </InstrumentParameter>
      <InstrumentParameter z:Id="14">
        <ChannelNumber>0</ChannelNumber>
        <InstrumentParameterType>Double</InstrumentParameterType>
        <IsMetaData>false</IsMetaData>
        <Name z:Id="15">1000</Name>
      </InstrumentParameter>
     </_items>
    <_size>13</_size>
    <_version>0</_version>
  </Outputs>
 </SimulatorConfigurationFile>
```

After deserialising the first item of the list iParams will be

```
id = 12
ChannelNumber = 0
InstrumentParamterType = Double
IsMetaData = false
Name = 0
```

### Thank you.

Yes I have tried the following. I do not have any problems loading the xdoc.

```
try
                {
                    // Get the actual output data
                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        xdoc.Load(rdr);

                    }

                    // Deserialize to IConfigurationFile
                    //XDocument xd = new XDocument(config);



                    // Use Linq
                    XElement el = XElement.Parse(xdoc.OuterXml);
                    rdr.Close();

                    var decs = el.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Outputs").Descendants();
                    //var items = el.Elements("Outputs").Elements("_items").Descendants().DescendantNodes();

                    List<InstrumentParameters> iParams = new List<InstrumentParameters>();

                    foreach (var dec in decs)
                    {
                        InstrumentParameters iParam = new InstrumentParameters();

                        IEnumerable<XNode> a = dec.Nodes();
                        IEnumerator<XNode> b = a.GetEnumerator();

                        while (b.MoveNext())
                        {
                            XNode c = b.Current;

                            //var n = c.Document.Descendants();
                           // c.
                        }
    }
```

I am unable to get the accurate values. Any help!

Comment: Hi Thank you. I have updated now.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Abe So now you're asking "how do I do it?" but there's plenty examples of how to convert XML to an instance of a class. I think you'd be better served by researching how and making an attempt, and only if you get stuck on that post a question, including an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve').

Comment: Yes I have tried the following. Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to xml would be easier to use

```
XNamespace z = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/";
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/ConfigurationInterfaces";
var list = XDocument.Load(filename)
            .Descendants(ns + "Outputs")
            .First()
            .Descendants(ns + "InstrumentParameter")
            .Select(e => new
            {
                id = (string)e.Attribute(z + "Id"),
                ChannelNumber = (string)e.Element(ns + "ChannelNumber"),
                InstrumentParameterType = (string)e.Element(ns + "InstrumentParameterType"),
                IsMetaData = (string)e.Element(ns + "IsMetaData"),
                Name = (string)e.Element(ns + "Name"),
            })
            .ToList();
```